# PHP array's I can't create a dynamic page

Tags: php, arrays

I've been using PHP arrays the create dynamic page but when I click on the link insted of showing the array I clicked It shows all of the array's here's the example I have created to show you guys http://arqetech.net/arrayTest/

Here's the code I've used:

1. The index.php Where I've listed a template for echoing out all the arrays:

   ```
   <ul>
       <?php foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) { ?>
       <li>
           <a href="dish.php?item=<?php echo $dish; ?>">
               <h1><?php echo $item[title]; ?></h1>
               <small><?php echo $item[utime]; ?></small>
           </a>
       </li>
       <?php } ?>
   </ul>
   ```
2. The arrays.php file where I put my array's:

`

```
$menuItems = array(

    "hello-world" => array(

        title => "Hello World, This Is My First POST!!!",
        utime => "June 13, 2014",
        content => "<p>You think water moves fast? You should see ice. It moves like it has a mind. Like it knows it killed the world once and got a taste for murder. After the avalanche, it took us a week to climb out. Now, I don't know exactly when we turned on each other, but I know that seven of us survived the slide... and only five made it out. Now we took an oath, that I'm breaking now. We said we'd say it was the snow that killed the other two, but it wasn't. Nature is lethal but it doesn't hold a candle to man. </p>"

    ),

    "my-second-post-weeheeeee" => array(

        title => "one+1",
        utime => "There was an ERROR showing some data!",
        content => "<p>You see? It's curious. Ted did figure it out - time travel. And when we get back, we gonna tell everyone. How it's possible, how it's done, what the dangers are. But then why fifty years in the future when the spacecraft encounters a black hole does the computer call it an 'unknown entry event'? Why don't they know? If they don't know, that means we never told anyone. And if we never told anyone it means we never made it back. Hence we die down here. Just as a matter of deductive logic. </p>"

    ),

);
```

?>`

3. The article.php Were PHP will dynamically put the array I clicked:

   `function strip_bad_chars( $item ) {
       $output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input );
       return $output;
   }

   if (isset($_GET['item'])) {

       $menuItem = strip_bad_chars( $_GET['item'] );
       $dish = $menuItems[$menuItem];

   }`


   ?>

   ```
   <ul>
       <li>
           <?php foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) { ?>
           <h1><?php echo $item[title]; ?></h1>
           <small><?php echo $item[utime]; ?></small>
           <?php echo $item[content]; ?>
           <?php } ?>
       </li>
   </ul>
   ```

But still doesn't echo the array link I clicked, Please help me (). Thak You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In article.php change this:

```
<?php foreach ($menuItems as $dish => $item) { ?>
<h1><?php echo $item[title]; ?></h1>
<small><?php echo $item[utime]; ?></small>
<?php echo $item[content]; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

To this:

```
<h1><?php echo $dish["title"]; ?></h1>
<small><?php echo $dish["utime"]; ?></small>
<?php echo $dish["content"]; ?>
```

Also,

Your strip_bad_chars will always return empty because your parameter is `$item` and you are using `$input` in `preg_replace`

So change:

```
function strip_bad_chars( $item ) {
    $output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input );
```

To something like this:

```
function strip_bad_chars( $input ) {
    $output = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/", "", $input );
```

Remember to check if `$dish` is setted before using its values. And quote your keys in `$menuItems` to avoid notices

You are assigning the item you clicked to `$dish` but you are not using it, instead you are showing all the values of `$menuItems` again.

Comment: Nope, It does not work. It just shows blank text! Anyway Thank You Very Much.

Comment: Yes I did checked for the errors after clicking on the links it just shows a blank page with just the layout, Check it out: http://arqetech.net/arrayTest/

Comment: @Arqetech on your question, in item 3, you say 'article.php' but in your site, when the user clicks on some item it redirects to 'dish.php', is that correct ? Show us what 'dish.php' contains if its content are different from 'article.php'

Comment: That was my typing mistake, Sorry